# Is there a way to loop through a files contents and use it in batch?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, file-handling

I'm working on a project in batch-file and need to read the contents of a file and print out the contents. I have a set up a `for /f` loop to go through the contents of the file, but it isn't working.

**The Code**

```
cd C:\Users\(name)
for /f %%G in (List.txt) (
    del /F /S %%G
    echo %errorlevel%
    pause
)
```

I have been Googling for about an hour now, and can't find anything which has worked for me. I was hoping that you guys could tell me what I'm doing wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default `delim`iters in `cmd` for the `for /F` loop is whitespace. Your code will split and assign the first word/number/line up until the first whitespace.

You need to tell the `for /f` loop to not use any delimiters. Also `usebackq` in order for you to double quote your file as that can also be a full path to the file with whitespace, i.e: `"C:\My Documents\Old Files\list.txt"`

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("List.txt") do del /F /S "%%~i"
```

then, `del` does not set the `errorlevel` and you will always get `0` returned. if you really want to check the result, redirect `stderr` to `stdout` and use `findstr` to determine if delete was successful.